# How to close a form, exit all process and open another form

Tags: c#, forms

How do I close a form and exit all the functions in that form and open another form?
I tried using application.exit(), I need something like that. But the problem is it shuts down all the forms and process, I need to end all the process in a form and close it and go to another form

Comment: If you exit all processes, then nothing will be running to open another form.

Answer (score 1):

In the program.cs file of your project, your main function would be something like

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Your execution ends when you close Form1.

You can change it to something like

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
```

Now in this case, when you close Form1, the execution would not end, but instead it will open Form2 and the program will run as long as form2 is open.